# Boolean Logical Syntax and MYSQL syntax Issue

Tags: android, mysql, sql, if-statement

Am not a learner to boolean expressions but this seems to be giving me a bit of an headache.
In my app when i search for a user,I am recieving certain values from my datase using this MYSQL statement.

```
SELECT `u3`.`username`, 
                      CASE WHEN `u3`.`username` IS NULL THEN 'Not Existing'
                      ELSE 'Existing' END is_following
                      FROM `userinfo` `u3` WHERE `u3`.`username` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($data)."%' OR `u3`.`email` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($data)."%'
                      UNION 
                      SELECT `u2`.`username`,
                      CASE WHEN `u2`.`username` IS NULL THEN 'Follow'
                      ELSE 'Following' END is_following
                      FROM
                      `userinfo` `u1` LEFT JOIN `followers` `f`
                      ON `u1`.`username` = `f`.`source_id`
                      LEFT JOIN `userinfo` `u2`
                      ON `f`.`destination_id` = `u2`.`username`
                      AND (`u2`.`username` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($data)."%' OR `u2`.`email` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($data)."%')
                      WHERE
                      `u1`.`username` = '$name'
```

Now the syntax above would return these set of values, a username and My own metadata.       For example it would return

`set of values 1: (davies and Existing)[if davies is in the userinfo table] AND (davies and Following)[if davies is following halex in the followers table]`

```
                                  OR
```

`set of values 2: (null and Not Existing)[if davies is not in the userinfo table] AND (null and not followed)[davies does not exist]`

```
                                  OR
```

`set of values 3: (davies and Existing)[if davies is in the userinfo table] AND (null and Not Following)[if davies is not following halex]`

These are the set of values i recieve and i need an if statement to sieve through so i can display to my users this simple information 
`davies and Following` OR `davies and Follow[if davies is not following halex]` OR `User Does not Exist`
Now am not sure if i should change the structure of my SOL statement or i could get a better way of handling this logic with `if and else` statements
This was the structure of my `if else` statement but it doesn't seem to work the way i want it to

```
if(username != null && metadata.contains("Existing"))//user exist
{
    value = username;
    //user exists but skip
}else
{
    if(username != null)
    {
        map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put(TAG_USERNAME, value);
            map.put(TAG_METADATA, metadata);
            listvalue.add(map);
    }else
   {
        //user does not exist
        Log.i("search ", "user does not exist");
      }
}
```

The codes above belongs to android.
Thanks any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks again in Advance.

Comment: What language are you writing your last code example in (the "if(username != null && metadata.contains("Existing"))//user exist...." example)?

Comment: @BenGribaudo the languague is android

Answer (score 0):

What if you split your query into two parts? Querying for one set of information at a time will make things simpler and easier to debug.

I could imagine doing something that looks like this (in pseudo-code):

```
query = "SELECT username 
         FROM `userinfo` `u3` 
         WHERE `u3`.`username` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($data)."%' 
             OR `u3`.`email` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($data)."%'"

var result = db.execute(query);
// set to true if the above query returns at least one row
bool user_exists = (result.RowCount() > 0)
var username = (user_exists)? result.GetRow().GetField("username") : null;

if(user_exists)//user exist
{
    value = username;
    //user exists but skip
} // ....
```

(I've only replicated the functionality pertaining to your UNION's first SELECT statement; the logic associated with the second statement can be similarly rewritten.)